# Is it possible to get video frames with flutter media_kit?

Tags: flutter, video-processing

I'm writing video processing application with flutter desktop using `media_kit`. I'd like to be able to compare neighbouring frames in runtime & modify the output before it hits user screen.
The application may open video files that user stores on local disk. I'm searching for some kind of interceptor capability.

As an option I'm considering the migration to `flutter_mjpeg` with their `preprocessor`s but in this case I would need to convert user video to `mjpeg` first and then sorce it with additional web server.

Can we do such interceptions with media_kit?